# Trying to get list of dropbox files to populate in asp.net view

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to populate a list of everything in a dropbox in asp.net. I have been trying for a few days to get this to work, but no matter what i try it keeps throwing exception and displaying the "alert(WRONG)". any help on what i might be doing wrong would be much appreciated. I do know the app-key is correct.

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
@section Scripts {

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/dropbox-datastores-1.2-latest.js">     </script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var client = new Dropbox.Client({ key: "APP-KEY" });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        readDir();
    })

    function readDir() {
        client.readdir("/CommunityDropBox", function (error, entries) {
            if (error) {
                alert('WRONG');
            } else {
                $('#placeholder').append("<br>The Dropbox contains: <br>" + entries.join(", <br>")).fadeIn();
            }
        })
    }
```

I have edited the code and now it is not authenticating. displays the alert(You are NOT connected).

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
@section Scripts {

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/dropbox-datastores-1.2-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var client = new Dropbox.Client({ key: "APP-KEY" });
client.authenticate({ interactive: false }, function (error) { if (error) { alert('Authentication error: ' + error); } });
if (client.isAuthenticated()) {
    alert("you are connected");
    readDir();
} else {
    alert("you are NOT connected");
}


//$(document).ready(function () {
//    readDir();
//})

function readDir() {
    client.readdir('/CommunityDropBox', function (error, entries) {
        if (error) {
            alert('WRONG: ' + error);
        } else {
            $('#placeholder').append("<br>The Dropbox contains: <br>" + entries.join(", <br>")).fadeIn();
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

Comment: there is a </script> at the end. just to clarify.

Comment: do you have a test/demo api key for us to use?

Comment: Is `error` an object of some sort, or is it just a boolean value? If it's an object, why don't you use it to figure out what's going wrong?

Comment: here is the alert with the error included... https://postimg.org/image/fujnxx995/

Comment: and i will give a test api key in a few...

Comment: the error is `{method: "GET", url: "https://api19.dropbox.com/1/metadata/auto/Communit…d=w7lu2f4ash282mm&include_deleted=false&list=true", status: 400, responseText: "{"error_description": "No auth function available for given request", "error": "invalid_request"}", response: Object}`

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this issue by replacing the key with the access-token. So that line now looks like this:

```
var client = new Dropbox.Client({ token: "ACCESS-TOKEN" });
```